# Inverse gaussian regression using scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to train data using sci kit, I want to use inverse gaussian as a regressor but I do not see that in the package, but I do see a section in the docs that mentions about GLM's(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html). Is there a way that an existing technique given in it can be modified for inverse gaussian ?? or is there any other way using scikit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually scikit-learn doesn't really have many generalized linear models, and the statsmodels package might be better suited.

Comment: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.families.family.InverseGaussian.html